# Why `type alias` a type that is defined the same way in another module?

Tags: module, elm, type-alias

For example, from the documentation of the [`Task` type in the `Task` module](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Task#Task):

```
type alias Task err ok =
  Task err ok
```

Or from the source:

```
type alias Task x a =
  Platform.Task x a
```

I assume the answer is to make it possible to expose it from the module being defined as its own. Is this correct?

---

UPDATE:
Chad Gilbert brings up a good point mentioning [`Platform` primitives](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/master/src/Process.elm#L66), such as the `Task` and `ProcessId` types, whose constructors are never used there, but it makes sense why these would be grouped at such a central place. Although his answer doesn't explain why they are aliased in their respective modules (see [Process.Id](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/master/src/Process.elm#L66) and Task.Task above).

I guess that without the aliasing, anyone trying to use the modules [`Task`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Task) and [`Process`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Process) would have to import these specific types (i.e., `Platform.Task`, `Platform.ProcessId`) because they are not imported by default (see [Elm's default imports](https://github.com/elm-lang/core#default-imports)).

---

UPDATE_2:
Yet another example is [`Value`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Json-Decode#Value) in the module [`Json.Decode` module](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Json-Decode):

```
-- From the docs:
type alias Value = 
    Value

-- From the source:
type alias Value = JsEncode.Value
```

I think this proves my assumptions above, but I am reluctant to answer my question because I am new at Elm and could easily be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short I think you do that when you want your interface structured different to how you want to organize your implementation.

You can do this for several reasons, like:

1. You want to expose the same type from multiple modules because it makes more sense that way to the consumer of your package. At the same time you must have a single implementation because that's what makes sense from an engineering perspective (like in case of `Json.Encode/Decode.Value`).
2. Your type is opaque anyway (meaning the constructors are not exposed), and you just need it or want it to be defined in a place different to where it should be imported from. 
   I think this is the case of `Platform.Task`: Evan, apparently, wanted to organize all platform primitives in one file. However, from a consumer's perspective, it would be weird to import a `Platform.elm`. It would feel like an implementation detail exposed to the consumer of the library.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation on [`Platform.Task`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Platform#Task):

> Head over to the documentation for the [`Task`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Task) module for more
>   information on this. It is only defined here because it is a platform
>   primitive

There it is defined as:

```elm
type Task err ok = Task
```

... which doesn't really tell us much. `Task` is an opaque type and its internal `Task` constructor is never used. It is one of the fundamental primitives in the Elm Architecture and based on the comment above, seems only to be defined in `Platform` because it is a convenient grouping of platform-centric primitives.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `Platform.Task` and I should've put it in my question, but I was trying to understand the point of `type alias`ing it in the `Task` module. I guess all the primitive types are defined in `Platform`, and are aliased in their own modules so that one does not have to refer to them via their full name and they could be exported by their modules. (The same goes to [`Platform.ProcessId`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Platform#ProcessId) and the [`Id` type alias in `Process`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Process)).